# How do you write "Lesson (number X)"?

Tags: english-to-japanese, phrase-requests

For example, Lesson 19. Would it be:

> 1) 授業19
>   2) 十九番目の授業

Would I use 学課, instead of 授業?

I'm a complete beginner, as well, I am literally starting from scratch, on my own.

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

You can say one of the following:

- レッスン19 (common)
- 第【だい】19講【こう】 (traditional and stiff)
- 授業19 (make sense but less common)

19番目の授業 is grammatical but sounds like "the nineteenth lesson" rather than "lesson 19". 学課 usually refers to a 'course' rather than individual lessons.

Comment: This is good stuff. I will review it and potentially post a reply, in the form of a question.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I would say 第19課 is the most common, as that's what at least three of my textbooks use.